# .rsplit() | return empty string instead of `IndexError: list index out of range`

Tags: python, string, index-error

Instead of `rsplit()`, is there an alternative function that returns an empty string: `""`, and doesn't crash?

I want to return the *"second-half"* of a `key`'s string, and place it at the end of its respective `value`'s string. However, not always does a key have the `~` in its name.

If it doesn't have a *"tag"*: `~tag`, then I want to **return an empty string**.

Note: this might be easier without it being a dictionary-comprehension:

```
import random

DLM = '~'

programmatic_dict = {key: '{} {} {}'.format(val, DLM, key.rsplit(DLM, 1)[1]) if random.randint(0,9) == 9 else val for key, val in programmatic_dict.items()}  # 10% tag
```

**Minimal Code:** (resulting in the same error as the code above).

```
thisdict = {
  "brand~tag": "Ford",
  "model~tag": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}

DLM = '~'

for k in thisdict.keys():
    print(k.rsplit(DLM, 1)[1])
```

**Output:**

```
tag
tag
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-036aa5073b32> in <module>
      6 
      7 for k in thisdict.keys():
----> 8     print(k.rsplit(DLM, 1)[1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post.

Comment: Why don't you use the index 0, i.e. `k.rsplit(DLM, 1)[0]` ?

Comment: Your problem isn't the `rsplit`, it's trying to access index 1. The string `"year"` will be split into a list containing a single item, no index 1. If you want it to always return a list of length 2 then you'll need to write a small wrapper function of your own.

Comment: Ah, specifically `[1]` at the end

Comment: @Nechoj Because that would access say `brand` in `brand~test`. I'd want to return `test`, but sometimes that doesn't exist. Will update post to clarify

Comment: then you could use the index -1: `k.rsplit(DLM, 1)[-1]`
This gives the last element, even if the list has only 1 element

Comment: `~tag` is a placeholder for what I'm calling a *"tag". If it doesn't have a tag, then I want it to return an empty string. Updated post to clarify this point too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the tag at hand, or, an empty string, write your own match function, preferably based on regex. Example:

```
import re

thisdict = {
  "brand~test": "Ford",
  "model~test": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}


r = re.compile(r".+(~.+)")


def my_match(k):
    m = r.match(k)
    if m:
        return m[1][1:]
    else:
        return ""


for k in thisdict.keys():
    print(my_match(k))
```

Comment: It works isolated. Going to try implementing it, and will report back. Thank you